# How to make a sawtooth waveform look less like a staircase (DAC)?

Tags: dac, output, input, wave, waveform

I am making a 4-bit digital-analogue converter using an adder circuit with four inputs. Each input is a square wave of a specific frequency. The output of the DAC is meant to be a sawtooth waveform but instead looks very jagged like a staircase. How could I make it look more like a straight line without changing the frequency of the square waves?

Comment: Note that 4 bit only has 16 values (0000-1111), are these by coincidence the stair case values? If so, add more bits to your converter. Each bit adds twice the number of possible values.

Comment: How do you get from the square wave input to the 4-bit digital value?

Answer (score 2):

A stairstep waveform means that your DAC lacks an appropriate reconstruction filter:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_filter

In this case, an RC filter set to less than half the sampling frequency (ideally much less for a low order filter) will work.

Adding one will give you a smooth waveform, even with only 4 bits (but your SNR will be limited to 24 dB by quantization noise unless you add more bits or oversample).

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

- apply RC filter at the output to round off the transitions. This will also round off the fall transition which you may not want.
- use more bits
- use a different DAC methodology like sigma-delta ("one bit") or switched-current-source
- do it in analogue instead (see [this example from Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/8/825.html))